# Drools Method Inconsistency with TypeCasting

Tags: java, casting, drools

Not quite sure if anyone has experienced drools' inconsistency with Java method type cast.

The case we have is a method that has 3 arguments, where the third argument is defined as BigDecimal. However, the method worked with no errors with low volume by passing -1 to that argument - which gave us an impression that Drools is capable of automatically converting -1 to BigDecimal.

However, when the volume goes up, runtime error occurred due to the data type problem in the 3rd argument.

The inconsistency conclusion came with a list of 50 same exact test cases by using this method only, the test fails around 30th test cases.

Not quite sure if anyone has experienced above issue. If it does, I am very curious about how this is handled at your end.

Thanks!

Comment: Please share whether you're using the executable model or not, if you're using the MVEL dialect and possibly paste the consequence here. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A simple example rule and a unit test demonstrating your issue would be helpful.